# How to repeat a request/(to make loop)?

Tags: c#

I make a request to the server for 25sec, if something happens, connection stops and I get my values, if nothing - I get a json with an empty field when time is finished. 
How can I repeat my request in both cases?
By this time I was using a button for every request.

```
    string connect_lp = "http://" + response.response.server + "?act=a_check&key=" + response.response.key + "&ts=" + response.response.ts + "&wait=25&mode=2";
    string json_lp = client.DownloadString(connect_lp);
    RootObject response_lp = (RootObject)json_serializer.Deserialize(json_lp, typeof(RootObject));
```

Comment: Is this just supposed to happen forever? How does the user stop the loop when they want to?

Comment: @pquest I'm noob in coding, and learning to work with API. I want to check if there are some new messages inbox (in social network). So I think it should be forever.

Comment: You loop by making a loop. Loops work by meeting a condition. You sound like you already know the condition, so make a loop. `while`, `for`, `do`.... pick your poison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're just constantly polling forever for data or something, use a

```
while (true)
{
    // code goes here
}
```

loop.  If you're just polling until a certain condition exists, try a do/while loop:

```
do {
    // some stuff
} while (!condition);
```

The beauty of a do/while loop is that the content of the loop will **always** be executed at least once (note how the while check is at the bottom of the loop).  Contrast this to a traditional while loop, where the check is first, and so the body of the loop may never be run at all.

So in your case, you may want something like:

```
string connect_lp;
string json_lp;
RootObject response_lp;

do {
    connect_lp = "http://" + response.response.server + "?act=a_check&key=" + response.response.key + "&ts=" + response.response.ts + "&wait=25&mode=2";
    json_lp = client.DownloadString(connect_lp);
    response_lp = (RootObject)json_serializer.Deserialize(json_lp, typeof(RootObject));
    // do more stuff
} while (response_ip.IsNotEmpty()); // or whatever.
```